# Overriding civicrm_webform's postprocessing of contributions

Tags: api, webform-civicrm, contributions, hooks

I'm using hook_form_alter() to perform calculations on various contributions on a civicrm_webform. I'd like to use the totals of these calculations to update the contribution amount and event amounts rather than use civicrm_webform's postprocessing.

What is the best way to do this? Can I overwrite the CiviCRM totals through the API?